# How to turn on console logging for TwitterSource

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Based on the Flink Scala quickstart, I've created a sample job that uses `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.twitter.TwitterSource`.

I'm using a local streaming job manager `/start-local-streaming.sh`, and start the job with `~/flink-0.10.0/bin/flink run target/quickstart-0.1.jar`

In the TwitterSource sourcecode, I notice that there are logging statements of the INFO level. How can I get those logged to console?

Answer (score 3):

The Flink daemons are started in the background, that's why Flink is logging to log files in the `log/` directory.
To monitor these files, use `tail -f log/*`. This will print the log entries on the console.

Another approach would be to change the start scripts of Flink to start it in the foreground + change the `conf/log4j.properties` file to use the `ConsoleAppender`.

Comment: I already get logs, the problem is that I can't figure out how to enable the INFO logging that's included in the TwitterSource code.

Comment: The `TwitterSource` is using the normal logging framework of Flink. Message such as the initila `Initializing Twitter Streaming API connection` should appear in the logs.
Maybe the source is not starting/running as expected? Are you seeing in the log that tasks are being deployed?

Comment: See http://pastie.org/pastes/10606738/text for the code + log. (The "pizza" log message is outputted before the job is received, but not included in the paste). Did not get the "Initializing Twitter Streaming API connection" as expected.

Comment: BTW: using a proxy, I do see a connection being made to twitter streaming API, but get no response. That's the original problem, hence the need for logging.

Comment: The log you've pasted is the output of the client.
Can you check the contents of the `logs/flink-*-jobmanager-0-*.log` file?

Comment: Output of jobmanger log "flink-Bekker-jobmanager-0-placeholder.local.log": http://pastie.org/pastes/10617871/text

Comment: Okay, from the JobManager logs it seems that there was never a job submitted ever to the Flink cluster.
Are you using a LocalStreamExecutionEnvironment? Its important to use `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getEnvironment()?.

Comment: Yes, using StreamExecutionEnvironment. Also, a connection to twitter is made when inspecting via a proxy.